# Cannot Locate Uninitialized Constant Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, model, relationship

I am attempting to create a relationship whereby a project model is connected a tools model through a tooltagging however I am receiving the following error on the project show view:

uninitialized constant Project::Tooltagging

I have read this is likely due to a spelling/pluralization error but i am unsure of where the error may be occurring.

Comment: please show your code (model, controller and show.html.erb) so other people can help

Comment: The error is coming from your model Project. You need to specify explicitly `class_name` , `foreign_key` to use the correct associations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nileshkumar was correct in that the error was located in my Project model. The code throughout my app had been written as tooltagging whereas the model had been created as tool_tagging.